# Only one user can push/pull to github

Tags: linux, git, github

I have two CentOS servers that are set up the same. I created a git repo on server A and pushed it to github. I then cloned the repo on server B. At first, all seemed to be in order. I could commit on either server, push to the remote, and the pull on to the other server.

The problem is that my co-workers now cannot push or pull on server B (they *can* run git status or commit). Strangely, this applies to ALL repos on server B, not just the one I cloned. Here is the error they see:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I checked that they are in the collaborators lists (both as owners and on the team assigned to the repo).

I also tried changing to the root user and cloning the repo again--as root I received the same error as above. The global .gitconfig does not reference my user or key, and the local .git/config files are set to use SSH (git@github.com).

What would cause this error to happen all users but one? Where else should I be looking?

Comment: How does the URL for the remote look?

Comment: [remote "origin"] url = git@github.com:[company]/[reponame]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resolve this issue. I found the problem by running `ssh -T -vvv git@github.com` which showed different keys being used for my user vs. the other users on the server. The key being used generally was not tied to a user in our github account. The fix:

- Generated a new SSH key
- Added key to shared user on github account
- Updated .ssh/config to use the new key when accessing github.com

I am not certain how the SSH key got messed up, because it worked before. But this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Add '-v' to your git command as you run it to get more verbose output, that should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Oddly, no additional output results from the use of the verbose option.